# Showing a set is nonempty for subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to show $A=\{(0, q, w): q, w \in R\}$ is a subspace of $R^3.$ I am having trouble showing that the set is nonempty because of the parameters. Do I say, Let $q = 0$ and $w = 0$ and thus $(0,0,0) \in A$, thus A is non empty? Also, how do you go about graphing the space in $R^3$

Answer (score 2):

Yea, that seems enough if you mean $\mathbb{R}$ instead of $R$. In fact, you've shown that $A$ contains the identity of $\mathbb{R}^3$ as well. As for graphing, if you let both $q,w$ vary over $\mathbb{R}$, you'll find that $A$ spans $\mathbb{R}^2$ so it's the entire $y-z$ plane on a graph.